# c++ returning a const reference of an object

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm not sure how to deal with return type of this:

`const Derived& myClass::getDerived(){} const`.

myClass has a member variable `Base**b`:

```
#include "Base.h"
Class myClass
{
    public:
         virtual const Derived& getDerived() const;
    .....
    protected:
         Base**b;
}
```

Derived class is inherited from Base class:

```
Class Derived : public Base
{
    ....
}
```

I tried:`return b[indexOfDerived];` and the error is:`reference to type 'const Derived' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'Base *'`

I also tried:`return *this->b[indexOfDerived];` and the error is:`no viable conversion from returned value of type 'Part' to function return type 'const CPU'`

How do I return a const reference of an object? I'm so confused.

I initialized the variable `Base**b` in the constructor by the following code:

```
myClass::myClass()
{
     b = new Base*[size];
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
          b[i] = new Base();
     }
}
....
// deallocating memory in destructor by using delete and delete[]
....
```

Sorry for the bad syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your initialization, it is not possible.  A `const Derived&` can only refer to an object of type `Derived`, or of a class derived from `Derived`.

But you have only created objects of type `Base`. You do not have any objects of type `Derived`.

You could attempt this by writing:

```
virtual const Derived& getDerived() const
{
    return dynamic_cast<Derived const &>(*b[indexOfDerived]);
}
```

which will throw an exception if the pointer in question does not actually point to a `Derived`. (Which it won't, until you have a `new Derived` somewhere).

Comment: I actually works thanks! I just start to learning c++ and I haven't seen "dynamic_cast<>" or "static_cast<>" before. I understand casting in java and c, but not yet introduced to casting in c++, do you have any recommended article or links that introducing casting in c++? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to return `Derived`, then you should create `Derived`

```
b[i] = new Base();
```

You must cast to convert a `Base*` to a `Derived*`

```
const Derived& getDerived() const
{
    return *static_cast<Derived const*>( b[0] );
}
```

Consider using a `vector<Base*>` or better `vector<unique_ptr<Base>>` to help with memory management and exception safety issues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm starting to learn casting in c++, do you have any recommended links or article introducing this topic?

Comment: Maybe this will help you :  [Type conversions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)